# How to change monitor resolution?

Tags: 14.04, display, display-resolution

I have tried to edit System settings,but it shows builtin display.[image]

My monitor is LG IPS236V,23INCH.

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Park [Mobility Radeon HD 5430]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=fglrx_pci latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:fbdc0000-fbddffff ioport:de00(size=256) memory:fbd00000-fbd1ffff
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

First find out how the monitor is identified.

```
cat ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

That command will print out your monitor's current settings. Find the active display such as HDMI1 for me. Once your have your display figured out, you can change the settings with xrandr.

```
xrandr --output HDMI1 --mode 1920x1080
```

That will force my monitor connected to HDMI to be in 1080p.

If you really want to make this with GUI, you could edit monitors.xml with gedit.

```
gedit ~/.config/monitors.xml
```

In there you can change the height and width, then reboot.

Comment: cat: /home/mimi/.config/monitors.xml: No such file or directory

Comment: What should I try?

Answer (score -1):

I have had the same here. What helped for me is to change the driver of the display card.

You can try to change the driver by starting:

```
Additional Drivers
```

from the Dash button (top left icon)